# print progress bar while move files to folder with file and folder details

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

in my bash script I wrote this

```
echo "move file - $file to $folder  Start"
mv $file $folder
echo "move file - $file to $folder  Ended"
```

- file is under file system -  "/"
- folder is under file system - "/var"

so the script print like this

```
move file - file.txt to archive  Start
move file - file.txt to archive  Ended
```

but I want to print the output , like this ( with "." that will printed each 5 sec as progress bar )

```
move file - file.txt to archive  start........end
move file - repo.txt to archive  start.....end
move file - list.txt to archive  start.............................end
```

Comment: Are source and target on the same or on different file systems (e.g. use `df` to find out)? If same, the [rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) runs very quickly (microseconds at most).

Comment: they are on diff file system one is "/" and folder is "/var"

Comment: Please **edit your question** but don't comment it.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

Comment: done - see my update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rsync instead.

```
rsync --remove-source-files -P /src_folder/src_file /dst_folder/dst_file
```

`--remove-source-files`   sender removes synchronized files (non-dirs)

`-P`   progress

Output will something like this:

```
316,628,992 100%  132.31MB/s    0:00:02 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```